# How can I replace the first two characters of every row in a specific column using SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm working with a table. In the table there is a column called ticket number which contains several rows of data. All of the values in the row begin with `J2`. I'd like to change the first two characters of all the rows to `A3`. How can I use SQL to do this. I'm familiar with the replace function:

```
SELECT REPLACE ([ticket number],'J2','A3')
```

But clearly the example above will not work, since it will change all of the `J2` occurrences to `A3` while I need to replace the first one at the beginning of ticket number. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Ticket Number
J2F4T45T
J2J3J3J2
J25TGYHJ2
J2FFJ2J2
J2MG8NGJ2
```

The desired result should be:

```
Ticket Number
A3F4T45T
A3J3J3J2
A35TGYHJ2
A3FFJ2J2
A3MG8NGJ2
```

Comment: If you want to really change your source data then you need `UPDATE` (and not `SELECT`).

Comment: sorry i need to change the first two values of every row in the column. Just updated question

Comment: Please enhance your question with sufficient sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What is the criteria that used to order the `[ticket number]`, is it the `[ticket number]` it self?

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure what you mean by criteria however I've now shared some sample data.

Comment: So It's only the first two characters of each row that I'm interested in changing.

Comment: I meant that how can you decide which are the first two tickets, i.e. based on the ticket numbers sorted alphabetically from A-Z.

Comment: To be honest I haven't ordered the column, atleast not yet.

Comment: You said that you want to perform the replace for the first two tickets, but in the provided expected outputs (desired result image) all of the ticket numbers are replaced !

Comment: Yes I would like to change the first two characters of every row. Sorry the way I said it before was not very clear. I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: For all tickets `update tickets set ticket_number=replace(ticket_number,'J2','A3')`. For only the first two tickets it will be a little complex and depends on `DBMS` you are using.

Comment: The issue with this code is that if a ticket number is J2DFDFJ2. It gives: A3DFDFA3. However I'm only looking for the first two characters to be replaced.

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But you could try to use a right function to get all but the 1st two character from the ticket_number:

```
SELECT 'A3' + RIGHT(ticket_number ,len(ticket_number)-2)
```

And if you need to update the table you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE ticket
set ticket_number = 'A3' + RIGHT(ticket_number ,len(ticket_number)-2)
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65766202669c4226e9b463013f0a8893)

Comment: This was perfect. I posted another method in the answer section which also works.

Answer (score 0):

This is also another method:

```
UPDATE ticket
set ticket_number = STUFF(ticket_number,1,2,'A3')
```

Comment: You don't need a `CONCAT` with the `STUFF` function, simply `ticket_number = STUFF(ticket_number,1,2,'A3')`

Comment: Also, the `STUFF` function is not supported among all `DBMS`s, i.e. in `MySQL` it's `INSERT`, because of that I asked you in the comments about the `DBMS` you are using.

Comment: I amended it now. Thank you for letting me know.